# dalvikvm: Could not find class

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

I'm getting the following error and crash when running an avd with API 17-20.  I don't get this error with API 23.  I am using Android Studio 2.0.

```
05-06 02:31:48.252 1544-1544/com.xxx.android E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.xxx.android.Splash.access$super
05-06 02:31:48.252 1544-1544/com.xxx.android E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.xxx.android.Splash.access$super
05-06 02:31:48.252 1544-1544/com.xxx.android E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method com.xxx.android.Splash.access$super
05-06 02:31:48.252 1544-1544/com.xxx.android E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.Toolbar', referenced from method com.xxx.android.Splash.access$super
05-06 02:31:48.252 1544-1544/com.xxx.android E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription', referenced from method com.xxx.android.Splash.access$super
05-06 02:31:48.256 1544-1544/com.xxx.android E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.xxx.android.Splash.access$super
05-06 02:31:48.256 1544-1544/com.xxx.android E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.xxx.android.Splash.access$super
05-06 02:31:48.256 1544-1544/com.xxx.android E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.xxx.android.Splash.access$super
05-06 02:31:48.260 1544-1544/com.xxx.android E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.assist.AssistContent', referenced from method com.xxx.android.Splash.access$super
05-06 02:31:48.260 1544-1544/com.xxx.android E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.SearchEvent', referenced from method com.xxx.android.Splash.access$super
05-06 02:31:48.260 1544-1544/com.xxx.android E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.xxx.android.Splash.access$super
05-06 02:31:48.260 1544-1544/com.xxx.android E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.xxx.android.HomeScreen', referenced from method com.xxx.android.Splash.onCreate
05-06 02:31:48.772 1544-1544/com.xxx.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: com.xxx.android, PID: 1544
                                                               java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.xxx.android.HomeScreen
                                                                   at com.xxx.android.Splash.onCreate(Splash.java:28)
                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the questionable code:

```
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.xxx.android.HomeScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:name="xxxApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/StartupTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.xxx.android.Splash"
        android:theme="@style/StartupTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.xxx.android.HomeScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/xxxTheme">
        <!--android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">-->
    </activity>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: clean and build the project then try to run again.

Comment: clean and build makes no difference.

Comment: Have you declared the HomeScreen Activity in AndroidManifest?

Comment: Yes, just edited to show AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: did you fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is an error with the emulator you're using. The AVD is not installed properly and the stack trace shows that the launcher of the device is throwing exceptions.